# How to get realtime output from php as it happens?

Tags: php, echo, real-time

How to get real-time output from php as it happens ? without storing all in memory/buffer and echoing all at once to the browser ?

if i create a realtime-echo.php

```
<?php
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
{
echo $i;
sleep(1);
}
```

and access it from Internet browser it gives following output , after 9-10 seconds.

```
0123456789
```

but what i am willing the output to be is, when i access the php file from my browser it should give

0

then wait 1 second then add "1" after the "0" 
then wait 1 second then add "2" after the "1"
and so on.

idk what its called like animation/real-time .

How do  achieve this ?

I am working on the project where i need the constant output as it happens so i can keep eye on whats happening and where its going.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Use [`flush()`](http://php.net/flush) function when you want the current output to be displayed.

A quick example:

```
<?php
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
   echo '<p>' . $i . '</p>';
   flush();
   sleep(1);
}
?>
```

If you are using output buffering, you also need to call [`ob_flush()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php)

Note: Some versions of Microsoft Internet Explorer will only start to display the page after they have received 256 bytes of output, so you may need to send extra whitespace before flushing to get those browsers to display the page.

Something like this:

```
<?php
echo str_repeat(" ", 256); 
flush();
?>
```

Working example (without `ob_start()` function):

```
<?php
echo str_repeat(" ", 256);
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++)
{
    sleep(1);
    echo '<p>' . $i . '</p>';
    flush();
}
?>
```

Comment: i tried your first code on my WAMP and it thorws all at once after waiting for 10 seconds , i am trying your second code

Comment: Ok, let me make other revision.

Comment: still the same, i guess i am missing something , i have even added // Turn off output buffering
ini_set('output_buffering', 'off');
// Turn off PHP output compression
ini_set('zlib.output_compression', false);

Comment: @AmbroseBwangatto, this code should work. But it also related to your webserver. http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php

Comment: this works for me: <?php echo str_repeat(" ", 256); for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) { sleep(1); echo '<p>' . $i . '</p>'; flush(); } ?>

Comment: Notice that the HTTP protocol has a certain packaging in mind, your output will not be presented in smaller steps as the packaging allowes for

Comment: Outputing a lot of whitespace was actually the only way I could "break through all the buffers" in my case. I basically appended 40k spaces after each echo call, and that does it. It's greatly inefficient, but as I've said, in my case it was the only option.

Answer (score 6):

Output buffering may be turned on which prevents realtime output. 
So you need an `echo` in combination with `flush()` and `ob_flush()`.

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php#109314

```
header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
echo 'Begin ...<br />';
for( $i = 0 ; $i < 10 ; $i++ ){
    echo $i . '<br />';
    flush();
    ob_flush();
    sleep(1);
}
echo 'End ...<br />';
```

I tried to create a fiddle but `sleep()` was not allowed in a fiddle. So I created a GIF.

[image]

Comment: I tested out your example using node.js to get the stream from PHP and it looks like this does work. However, my webserver was configured to send out larger sized chunks, so the streaming might not always be immediately evident

Comment: @AdamF In the `php.ini` on my server I had the output_buffering directive like this: `output_buffering = 4096`. How do you deal with the streaming problem you describe?

Comment: @Julian, don't know if that helps, but if you need to change the ini settings locally on the code, you can add a line like this:
`ini_set('output_buffering', 512);`

Answer (score 5):

PHP is an interpreted server language. Using PHP you can create some local programs or implement the server-side of a web application. If you run your PHP code in command-line, then your code should work as expected. However, if you use your PHP through the browser, then there is a request-response policy applicable at HTTP. If you send a request to the browser, then you will only receive the response of the server *when the script was executed*. So, you request the page through a browser and then wait for the response. The server receives the request and echoes out ten numbers with a second sleep between them. **After the server finishes its job it sends the response back to your browser which will get the ten numbers in a single batch**. This is why you are experiencing that you wait for ten seconds and then all the output is displayed at once: It is because the server executed the sleeps and collected your echoes and then sent them back to your browser which was just displaying it.

Of course, if you want to display ten server responses in your browser then you will have to do better. Maybe you can use [polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code) (using the `setInterval` or the `setTimeout` function of Javascript you are waiting the seconds **in your client-side** and send the post requests after that to the server using `$.ajax`, for instance. At the server you handle the request and respond with the correct output. Your client-side should have a callback where you handle the response of the server and displays it accordingly).

Comment: does this means flush() doesnt do what i am looking for ? i can use ajax too if that solves the issue. thanks

Comment: The sleep method successfully sleeps between your echoes. However, the problem is that PHP sends the answer back to the browser running on the user's computer after the PHP script was executed, so you wait for 10 seconds without seeing anything displayed and then, the response arrives and everything is displayed at once.

Comment: @LajosArpad, I believe you commented about sleep(), while AMB asked about flush() in his comment. I second his question: the method with flush() and ob_flush() of Paul works for me. But your answer implies that it actually shouldn't. Please clarify.

Comment: @texnic I explained the reason of the behavior AMB described. flush and ob_flush attempts to send the current content to the client.