# How to add delay between two echos in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm trying to add a 5 seconds delay between each echo to allow the user the see the status.

My code

```
add_action( 'gform_pre_submission_8', 'pre_submission_handlerr' );

function pre_submission_handlerr( $form ) {

$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
global $wpdb; 


$checkip = $_POST['input_8'];

echo "IP Requested: . $checkip";

$result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * from wp_gf_entry_meta WHERE meta_value like '$checkip');"); 

  if ( $result == 1) {
  $_POST['input_7'] = 'Approved';
  sleep(5);
  echo "Status: Found";
  sleep(5);

 }

if ( $result == 0) {
$_POST['input_7'] = 'Not Approved';
echo "Status: Not Found";
}
   }
```

However, I see the delay is actually at the beginning and there no delay where I want it to be (between the two echo)

PHP Snippet in WordPress (Gravity Form)

Any feedback would be appreciated

Thanks!
Nathalie

Comment: You can use flush() with your sleep() https://stackoverflow.com/a/19085197/11274409

Comment: It is probably a better idea to output everything directly and let Javascript do something after 5 seconds. That way you don't leave a connection open.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: This is a problem best solved with javascript.

Comment: Another advantage of Javascript is that it is timed in the browser of the user, and therefore the timing is far more reliable.

Comment: For JavaScript, can someone point me to the right direction (example, similar issue, etc) that I can take a look at and figure things out ? :)

Answer (score 0):

It may not be the best idea to do so. There should be other ways that you might async your script, I'm guessing using `Promises` in your client side.

However, this might help you to do so:

```
add_action('gform_pre_submission_8', 'pre_submission_handlerr');

function preSubmissionHandlerr($form)
{
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    global $wpdb;
    $checkip = $_POST['input_8'];
    echo "IP Requested: . $checkip";

    $result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * from wp_gf_entry_meta WHERE meta_value like '$checkip');");

    if ($result == 1) {
        $_POST['input_7'] = 'Approved';
        flush();
        sleep(5);
        flush();
        echo "Status: Found";
        flush();
        sleep(5);

    }

    if ($result == 0) {
        $_POST['input_7'] = 'Not Approved';
        echo "Status: Not Found";
    }
}
```

Or you could use `ob_implicit_flush();` if you wish, and that might work too, maybe once or multiple times:

```
add_action('gform_pre_submission_8', 'pre_submission_handlerr');

function preSubmissionHandlerr($form)
{
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    global $wpdb;
    $checkip = $_POST['input_8'];
    echo "IP Requested: . $checkip";

    $result = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * from wp_gf_entry_meta WHERE meta_value like '$checkip');");

    if ($result == 1) {
        ob_implicit_flush(true);
        $_POST['input_7'] = 'Approved';
        sleep(5);
        ob_implicit_flush(false);

        ob_implicit_flush(true);
        echo "Status: Found";
        sleep(5);
        ob_implicit_flush(false);

    }

    if ($result == 0) {
        $_POST['input_7'] = 'Not Approved';
        echo "Status: Not Found";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx Emma.  I tried the code but there seems to be a delay but the output is being displayed quickly at the end and disappear  The sleep (5) after Status Found is definitely not working