# echo to console in CLI script doesn't show in PHP CI4 (Code Igniter 4) until after the script terminates, how can I make it show in real-time?

Tags: php, command-line-interface, echo, codeigniter-4

Echoing to the console in a CLI script doesn't show in CI4 (Code Igniter 4) until after the script terminates/ends/exits.

I believe this is some security feature but in a CLI run, I'd like to be able to see those echo statements in real-time and not have to exit or stop my code to see what happened.

Is there a configuration for this somewhere or some way to change it easily? I've tried to research this but I must be searching for the wrong terminology, everything I find is irrelevant.

I am using PHP 8.0

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Flush the output buffer? https://stackoverflow.com/q/19085188/1427878

Comment: ugh, I hope that's not my only option lol. Lots of code changes for every echo. Good thought though. I'll have to try it. -- unfortunately, that doesn't work, behavior remains the same with both flushes added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that we can use CI4's built-in CLI write function and it will immediately output:

```
use CodeIgniter\CLI\CLI;

...

CLI::write('See this text immediately');
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the output buffer, and the gzip-zlib as well (for webpages), are turned off in your php.ini

```
output_buffering = Off
zlib.output_compression = Off
```

Comment: Thanks, I appended these to the end of my ini file located via php --ini and restarted apache but no changes, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you check printing out a phpinfo()?